# Percentage of a upper level div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a horizontal, 930px wide menu, that stretches across the whole width of a page on <768px resolution. At the moment, only the inline anchor tags are clickable, but I found out it is quite impossible to make the whole li clickable while mantaining 'responsivness'. I've tried numerous solutions, right now I am using display:table on the ul, display:table-cell on the li and a JS to make it stretch across the whole container. Works great on <768px, but at 930px, paddings inbetween anchor and their li containers become uneven. Screenshot and code below. (last menu item has display:none and is there because of the mobile menu version, please ignore it)

So, is there a way to have anchor paddings as percentages of the width of the **UL**? If not, how can I solve this?

HTML:

```
<!-- Responsive menu -->
 <nav class="btn1content btncontent main-menu-wrapper hidden">
  <ul class="main-menu" align="right">
   <li class="item cyan"><a href="../tmpl/index.html"  title="">Úvod</a></li>
   <li class="item orange active"><a href="../tmpl/aktuality.html"  title="">Aktuality</a></li>
   <li class="item yellow"><a href="#"  title="">Domény</a></li>
   <li class="item brown"><a href="#"  title="">Registrátori</a></li>
   <li class="item blue"><a href="#"  title="">CMS & Frameworky</a></li>
   <li class="item pink"><a href="#"  title="">Trendy</a></li>
   <li class="item green "><a href="#" title="">Zoznam</a></li>
   <li class="item sand"><a href="#"  title="">Sledovanie domén</a></li>
   <li class="item darkgray"><a href="#"  title="">Kontakt</a></li>
   <li class="item item-last"><a href="#" title=""></a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Clear -->
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.main-header .main-menu-wrapper  {
    margin: -3px auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    position: static;
    height: auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.main-header .main-menu-wrapper .main-menu {
    display: table-row;
}

.main-header .main-menu-wrapper .item {
    text-align: center;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 3px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    height: auto;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}

.main-header .main-menu-wrapper .item a {
    padding: 42px 0;
}
```

Screenshot (up - what it looks like now, below - what it should look like) 
p.s. can't post pictures yet

https://i.stack.imgur.com/An4hh.png

Demo is up on

http://statistikydomen.magnetica-hosting.sk/tmpl/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
.main-header .main-menu-wrapper .item a {
    padding: 42px 0;
}
```

To this:

```
.main-header .main-menu-wrapper .item a {
    display: block;
}
```

That will make your anchors fill out to the width of their parents (the `li` elements).

The `table-cell` display of those `li` will make the browser calculate a propert width for each item. Those widths might vary a little, based on the length of the captions and possibly even the browser/version, but I wouldn't worry too much about that. Responsive isn't always pixel perfect. Any way, you will get a quite nice division of the elements and the anchors will fill the entire width of the li, making the whole menu area clickable.

PS:

- Formally you will have to write `&` in `CMS & Frameworky` as `&amp;`.
- You don't need the 'clear' div if you implement one of the tricks
  described here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/